# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, .net, excel, memory, protected

I am trying to open and Excel 2000 file. When I try this with Excel 2007 it is working fine but when I checked it on the development server it is not working. It is thowing an error while opening the excel file. I am using the below code.

```
 // file
 string sFile = @"c:\testfile.xls";

 // create excel file
 Excel.Application oExcel;
 Excel.Workbook oBook;
 Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();


oExcel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFile, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 
    0, true, true, false);
oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
oSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Successfully Created";
oSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "Sample excel updated";
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;

// save & close
oBook.Close(true, sFile,false);
oExcel.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
oExcel = null;
GC.Collect();
```

The error msg is  the following:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to
>   read or write  protected memory. This is often an indication that
>   other memory is corrupt.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object
>   Upda teLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object
>   WriteResPasswor d, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin,
>   Object Delimiter, Object Edi table, Object Notify, Object Converter,
>   Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object Co rruptLoad)   at
>   TestExcel.Program.Main(String[] args)"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's almost impossible to say.  You say:

> but when I checked it on the development server it is not working

This implies somewhat that this is a service.  If that is the case, then there's not much you can do, [Microsoft Office applications are not designed to run in services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Answer (score 0):

Does your server also have Office 2007 installed? It seems to me like that is not the case, which means you need to use older libraries that are compatible with the version installed on your server.